# Add Data of previous months in next month,Historization of data in SAP HANA Calculation View

Tags: sql, hana

Historization means we show add data of previous months to upcoming months.

For eg: Input:

```
ID  STATUS  YEAR MONTH
A   OPEN    2017-01
A   CLOSED  2017-03
B   OPEN    2017-01
B   Closed  2017-05
```

My output:

```
YEAR MONTH     COUNT-OPEN                         COUNT-CLOSED
2017-01     2(both A & B OPEN)                      0
2017-02     2(FROM 201701)                          0
2017-03     2(from 2017-02)-1(A Closed now)=1   1
2017-04     1(from 201703)=1                    1(from prev month)
2017-05     1-1(b closed)=0                     1+1(b closed)=2
```

Values are the actual output I have just written the formula to make you understand the logic.

I need to add data to open/closed from previous months to upcoming months, is it possible in SAP HANA without use of Cursors?

As I can do it with Cursors, If any other logic exist please help me with it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the solution of this requirement, I can suggest you to use a numbers table on HANA database. In the following part, I've shared the SQLScript codes in which I've used this [numbers table function](http://www.kodyaz.com/sap-abap/create-numbers-table-function-on-sap-hana-database.aspx) for creating the series of dates in a specific range

```
with input as (
    select
        id,
        status,
        year,
        cast(month as integer) month,
        case when status = 'OPEN' then 1 else -1 end as COUNT_OPEN,
        case when status = 'CLOSED' then 1 else 0 end as COUNT_CLOSED
    from Historization
)
SELECT 
    y.rownum as year,
    m.rownum as month,
    (select sum(COUNT_OPEN) from input where  year <= y.rownum and month <= m.rownum) as COUNT_OPEN,
    (select sum(COUNT_CLOSED) from input where  year <= y.rownum and month <= m.rownum) as COUNT_CLOSED
FROM Numbers_Table(2017) as y
CROSS JOIN Numbers_Table(12) as m
where y.rownum = 2017
order by y.rownum, m.rownum
```

You see I used the numbers function "Numbers_Table" in the outer SELECT statement which creates the FROM part of the join clause

For simulating the COUNTs, I assume that a record cannot be CLOSED before it is OPENED so, when it is in OPEN status I add 1 to OPEN state count.
While the record is closing, I add 1 to CLOSED state. But the trick here is, I use -1 for OPEN state for a closing item.
SUM() aggregation function helps me to get the final row data

The output is as follows,

[image]